# Using one RequireJS project within another RequireJS project

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a RequireJS project I am working on with the following structure:
    Project/
        index.html
        src/
            main.js
            projectcomponent.js
        lib/
            require.js

main.js is the entry point of the Require application and has the following require.config inside it:

```
require.config
    baseUrl: "./"
```

main.js returns an object.

I want to use this entire project as a module inside another RequireJS project. I attempted to use r.js (the RequireJS optimisation tool) to reduce the project to a single file, which worked - but as it relied on RequireJS, its config conflicted with the config of the parent project I wanted to use *this* project as a module for.

How can I use one RequireJS project as a module inside another RequireJS project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get round this by using almond (https://github.com/jrburke/almond) to replace the require.js dependency, making the first project a fully encapsulated single file.

There's some further explanation and relevant links on the RequireJS site: http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-optimization.html#wrap

Comment: This seems exactly what I want! I'll implement it and if it works I shall then return to give you +15 or whatever a best answer is these days :D